# Difference between Generic collection and arrays of specific datatype

Tags: c#

If I am not wrong Generic collection stores the objects of specific types.
For example, `List<String>` stores objects of only String types.
Also `String[] arr = new String[size]` stores the objects of String types.
Both also support `IEnumerable` interface.
So I want to know the differences between Generic Collection and Arrays of Specific types.

Comment: It is all about how do you want to use it. Array is obviously more compact (take less space), but also less flexible. You can convert any into any, but conversion takes time and memory. If you expect to have operations like `insert`, `add`, `delete`, `sort`, then use `List<>`. If your priority is to `find` by key, then both are bad (use `Hashtable` to example). Arrays are good to hold fixed size data (to example, to organize cyclic buffer) or for size (memory) optimizing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `array` is fixed size. You define the size up front and that's it. A collection like `List<T>` is of variable size. It supports adding and removing items from the collection. Behind the scenes a `List<T>` uses an `array` to store the items. It's smart enough to re-size the `array` whenever necessary.

So you shouldn't think about generic vs array but collection vs array. There are also non-generic arrays but there are few scenarios where you would use those.

You can find the documentation for `List<T>` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).